# Compactness of Sets of Probability Measures on countable space

Tags: probability, general-topology, measure-theory, compactness

Consider the set of probability measures on a countable space $X$. I am wondering if such sets are compact?

As a hint, I know that for finite $X$, the set is indeed compact as a closed and bounded subset in $R^{|X|}$.

However, I am having trouble for countable space as now in infinite dimension.

Comment: $(\delta_n)$ is a counter-example, it you are considering compactness w.r.t. weak convergence of measures.

Comment: I don't understand how $\delta_n$ is a counter example. Indeed, I am considering weak topology.

Comment: If $X$ is compact, then the set of probability measures on $X$ is compact as well. This follows from Prohorov's Theorem (Theorem 23.2 in Kallenberg, 2002).

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\mathbb N$ with its usual metric.  $(\delta_n)$ is a counter-example. [$\delta_n(A)=1$ if $n \in A$ and $0$ otherwise]. $\int f d\delta_n=f(n)$ and $\lim f(n)$ need not exits: take $f(n)=1$ for $n$ even and $f(n)=0$ for $n$ odd.
[Recall that any real valued function on $\mathbb N$ is continuous].